# Image downloading issue objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, image, download, download-manager

I am a Objective c programmer, I am facing a problem while downloading a handsome amount of images from server into the app.
At the moment I am using straight forward strategy i.e. Queue up the images alongside main queue. Images are almost 2000 with different sizes.
The problem is it takes a very long time to download e.g. It downloads only 10% overnight. What would be the best way to download them in order to Maximize the user experience with minimal effort.

Thanks.

Comment: It depends on where the bottleneck is. If it is your network then there is nothing you can do about it (besides upgrading it)

Comment: I don't think so that network is an issue, because I am using 3G or wifi not edge.